# How to read attributes from a custom @FacesConverter

Tags: jsf

I have written the following JSF Converter class:

```java
@FacesConverter("imixsDateConverter")
public class ImixsDateConverter implements Converter {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    private static final String DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = "CET"; // Set the timezone to CET

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return ""; // Convert empty string to null
        }
        component.get
        try {
            String pattern = DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN;
            String timezone = DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE;
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
            return dateFormat.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error converting date", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || "".equals(value)) {
            return ""; // Convert null to empty string
        }

        if (value instanceof Date) {
            String pattern = DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN;
            String timezone = DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE;
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
            return dateFormat.format((Date) value);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value type: " + value.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to make it more configurable providing attributes like

```xml
<h:inputText value="#{workitem.item[item.name]}">
    <f:converter converterId="imixsDateConverter"
    timeZone="#{message.timeZone}"
    pattern="#{message.datePatternShort}" />
```

or like this:

```xml
<h:inputText value="#{workitem.item[item.name]}">
    <f:converter converterId="imixsDateConverter">
        <f:attribute name="pattern" value="#{message.datePatternShort}" />
        <f:attribute name="timeZone" value="#{message.timeZone}" />
    </f:converter>
```

But I can't read the attributes. I already tried the methods

```
Map<Object, Object> map = context.getAttributes();
```

and

```
Map<String, Object> map = component.getAttributes();
```

But the attributes defined in my JSF page are not included in this attribute maps.

How can I access these custom attributes?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question myself:

The `f:attribute` tag has to be placed inside the input component and not in the `f:converter` tag:

```xml
    <h:inputText value="#{workitem.item[item.name]}" >
        <f:converter converterId="imixsDateConverter" />
        <f:attribute name="pattern" value="#{message.datePatternShort}" />
        <f:attribute name="timeZone" value="#{message.timeZone}" />
    </h:inputText>
```

In this way the attributes can be read by the converter class with:

```java
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
       component.getAttributes().get("pattern");
      ....
    }
```